# How to use Visca Commands to operate Camera in C#

Tags: c#, camera

I need to use *Visca Commands* with visca compatible camera within `c#` application. Any idea how could I start with writing visca command compatible application to operate camera in `c#`.

I have gone threw library [Visca Win Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/viscawinlib/) but not able to find how could I use visca commands within `c#`.

Comment: This project looks promising: https://github.com/reflex33/visca

Comment: This project looks promising: https://github.com/reflex33/visca